Is it possible to attach multiple ADM profiles or multiple Security Profiles for a single Application?
I need to rotate ADM OAuth ClientSecret but the portal only allows "regenerating" it, with the option to keep the existing one valid for some predefined period of time. There is therefore a risk, that if I won't be able to rotate the ClientSecret on my side in that period of time for some reason, I will end up with a system completely unable to send any messages at all. Having several concurrent valid secrets would allow me to do the rotation without such risks. Is it possible to achieve that? Since there seems to be 1 OAuth Credential for 1 Security Profile, maybe it is possible to attach multiple ADM profiles or multiple Security Profiles to a single Application?
